# Mi programa no pide el segundo valor Java

Tags: java, java-8

Necesito ayuda en mi código en java, estoy haciendo un menú con opciones funcionales pero con interfaz gráfica, al pulsar las opciones como por ejemplo de sumar me pide el primer valor pero el segundo no me lo pide y hasta allí llega el programa se cierra solo, la idea seria que pidiera el segundo valor y mostrara en pantalla el resultado, lo otro es que en otras opciones no muestra el dato en el menú si no en la consola. Si alguien tuviera el tiempo y el conocimiento para que revisara el código y corrigiera y si pudiera explicarme un poco de que fue el error se los agradecería de verdad necesito la ayuda.

Aquí dejo el link de descarga del código esta en un documento .txt
https://www.dropbox.com/s/sbhfm2q98pllg1n/codigo.txt?dl=0

Este es el código:

```
package jesus.menu;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class JesusMenu {
static double numero;
static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //Sirve para recoger texto por consola
static int select = -1; //Es la opción elegida por el usuario
static double num1 = 0, num2 = 0; //Son las variables

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);//Esto es para que se lean datos desde el teclado.
Calendar fecha = new GregorianCalendar();   //Se agrega el objeto calendario
//Se declaran las variables para la fecha y hora
int ano = fecha.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mes = fecha.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int dia = fecha.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int hora = fecha.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minuto = fecha.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int segundo = fecha.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    String strOpcion;
    int opcion = 0;

    do{
        strOpcion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("** ELIJA UNA OPCION DEL MENU **:\n\n" +
                                                "1.- Sumar\n" +
                                                "2.- Restar\n" +
                                                "3.- Multiplicar\n" +
                                                "4.- Dividir\n" +
                                                "5.- Raiz de un numero\n" +
                                                "6.- Mostrar Fecha\n" +
                                                "7.- Mostar Hora\n" +
                                                "8.- Genera un numero aleatorio\n" +
                                                "9.- Resolucion\n" +
                                                "0.- Salir\n");
    try{
        opcion = Integer.parseInt(strOpcion);






    }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"***Hubo un Error***");
    }
    switch(opcion){
    case 1: 
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce un numero para sumarlo");
    pideNumeros();
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(num1+" + "+num2+" = "+(num1+num2));
            break;
case 2:
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce un numero para restarlo");
    pideNumeros();
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(num1+" - "+num2+" = "+(num1-num2));
    break;
case 3: 
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce un numero para multiplicarlo");
    pideNumeros();
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(num1+" * "+num2+" = "+(num1*num2));
            break;
case 4: 
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce un numero para dividirlo");
    pideNumeros();
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(num1+" / "+num2+" = "+(num1/num2));
    break;
case 5:
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce el Numero para Obtener su Raiz");
    double numeros=teclado.nextInt();
    double resultado=Math.sqrt(numeros);
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("El resultado es: "+resultado);
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n");
    break;
case 6:
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("nFecha Actual: " + dia + "/" + (mes+1) + "/" + ano);
    break;
case 7:
    System.out.printf("Hora Actual: %02d:%02d:%02d %n", hora, minuto, segundo);
    break;
case 8:
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("El numero generado es: ");
    for (int i=0; i<1; i++){
    numeros=Math.random()*50;
    System.out.println(numeros);
    System.out.println("");
    }
    break;
case 9:
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Se mostrara la resolucion de la pantalla");
    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();//Se obtiene el tamaño de la pantalla
    int sr = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution();//Se obtiene la resolucion de la pantalla
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Tamaño de pantalla: " + d.width + "x" + d.height);
    break;
case 0: 
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\nHasta Luego...\n");
    break;
default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Opcion no valida");break;

    }

    }while(opcion!=0);
}

private static void pideNumeros() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

}
```

Se los agradecería demasiado. GRACIAS.

Comment: Agrega el codigo que tienes hasta ahora, y el error que obtienes a tu pregunta, asi podemos ayudarte de mejor manera.

Comment: Es que el codigo es tiene 114 lineas esta terminado, por consola funciona perfecto pero por menu no me da error al pedir el segundo valor y mostrar el resultado. Como es muy extenso lo agregue a un link para que se descargue. Esta arriba igual es este mismo : https://www.dropbox.com/s/sbhfm2q98pllg1n/codigo.txt?dl=0

Comment: listo ya lo puse no sabia eso soy nuevo aqui. gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He probado tu codigo y lanza un `exception` por que tu método `pideNumeros()` esta lanzado un  `throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");`

Te dejo el código para realizar la suma, es decir la opcion 1 de tu programa.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class JesusMenu {

    static double numero;
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //Sirve para recoger texto por consola
    static int select = -1; //Es la opción elegida por el usuario
    static double num1 = 0, num2 = 0; //Son las variables

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);//Esto es para que se lean datos desde el teclado.
    Calendar fecha = new GregorianCalendar();   //Se agrega el objeto calendario
    //Se declaran las variables para la fecha y hora
    int ano = fecha.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mes = fecha.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dia = fecha.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int hora = fecha.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minuto = fecha.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int segundo = fecha.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        String strOpcion;
        int opcion = 0;

        do{
            strOpcion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("** ELIJA UNA OPCION DEL MENU **:\n\n" +
                                                    "1.- Sumar\n" +
                                                    "2.- Restar\n" +
                                                    "3.- Multiplicar\n" +
                                                    "4.- Dividir\n" +
                                                    "5.- Raiz de un numero\n" +
                                                    "6.- Mostrar Fecha\n" +
                                                    "7.- Mostar Hora\n" +
                                                    "8.- Genera un numero aleatorio\n" +
                                                    "9.- Resolucion\n" +
                                                    "0.- Salir\n");
        try{
            opcion = Integer.parseInt(strOpcion);
        }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"***Hubo un Error***");
        }
        switch(opcion){
        case 1: 
                num1 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce el primer numero"));
                num2 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce el segundo numero"));
                //pideNumeros(); //Comento el método para no lanzar un exception
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,num1+" + "+num2+" = "+(num1+num2));
            break;
    case 2:
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce un numero para restarlo");
        pideNumeros();
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(num1+" - "+num2+" = "+(num1-num2));
        break;
    case 3: 
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce un numero para multiplicarlo");
        pideNumeros();
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(num1+" * "+num2+" = "+(num1*num2));
                break;
    case 4: 
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce un numero para dividirlo");
        pideNumeros();
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(num1+" / "+num2+" = "+(num1/num2));
        break;
    case 5:
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce el Numero para Obtener su Raiz");
        double numeros=teclado.nextInt();
        double resultado=Math.sqrt(numeros);
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("El resultado es: "+resultado);
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n");
        break;
    case 6:
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("nFecha Actual: " + dia + "/" + (mes+1) + "/" + ano);
        break;
    case 7:
        System.out.printf("Hora Actual: %02d:%02d:%02d %n", hora, minuto, segundo);
        break;
    case 8:
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("El numero generado es: ");
        for (int i=0; i<1; i++){
        numeros=Math.random()*50;
        System.out.println(numeros);
        System.out.println("");
        }
        break;
    case 9:
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Se mostrara la resolucion de la pantalla");
        Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();//Se obtiene el tamaño de la pantalla
        int sr = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution();//Se obtiene la resolucion de la pantalla
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Tamaño de pantalla: " + d.width + "x" + d.height);
        break;
    case 0: 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\nHasta Luego...\n");
        break;
    default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Opcion no valida");break;

        }

        }while(opcion!=0);
    }

    private static void pideNumeros() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Si te das cuenta en el switch case 1 he comentado la llamada al metodo pideNumeros(), y en vez de eso estoy llamando la entrada de datos de los dos números a través de `Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce el primer numero"));`.

**EDIT en base a los comentarios**

Para realizar las operaciones que mencionas en los comentarios podrías hacer algo así:

```
      case 5:
           num1 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce el primer numero"));        
           double resultado=Math.sqrt(num1);
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El resultado es: "+resultado);

         break;
    case 6:
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Fecha Actual: " + dia + "/" + (mes+1) + "/" + ano);
        break;
    case 7:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hora Actual: "+ hora + ":"+minuto+":"+segundo);
        //System.out.printf("Hora Actual: %02d:%02d:%02d %n", hora, minuto, segundo);
        break;
    case 8:
                double numeros=Math.random()*50;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El numero generado es: "+numeros);
        break;
```

Comment: Lo mismo tendría que hacer con el resto de las operaciones de matemática resta división y multiplicación no? y que me dices de la parte de mostrar la hora que sale por consola, la de generar un numero aleatorio que se salta la opción y la de raíz que pasa igual, por lo menos la parte de la fecha sale la fecha que es igual con la resolucion

Comment: Claro para las operaciones tendrías que hacer lo mismo. Ahora edito la respuesta con los cambios a las operaciones que dices.

Comment: Si ya edite las operaciones de resta, división y multiplicación y otras cosas en las otras opciones para que se mostraran bien me fije de los arreglos que hice y quedo bien, me faltan las que te dije. Llevaba dias pariendo por esto. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Ya agregue las opciones que dices, si la respuesta te fue útil marcala como solución a la misma, así también otros usuarios la pueden encontrar útil.

Comment: mi pana y en el case 5 que crees que le falte ya seria lo ultimo y si le dare como solucionada. Si puedes despues podrias revisar mi otra pregunta http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/12907/boton-funcional-en-java

Comment: Listo ya esta editada. Deberías leer un poco más, realmente es fácil de hacer cada operación. Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: El case 5 es el de la raiz y no ese no esta editado, al poner el digito y darle enter se cierra :( si debo aprender mas en java es que apenas estoy en esto y no nos explican nada :/ . Antes de irte porfa resuelveme eso y si puedes hoy o mañana revisame la otra pregunta que hize. Ah y como marco la pregunta como solucionada??? Es mi primera vez en la pagina

Comment: Si es que no le puse formato al código, ahora ya esta editada, para dar como solucionada dale click al check que aparece al lado izquierdo de la respuesta.

Comment: aah ok, listo gracias mi pana me salvaste ya con esto tengo una idea para lo demas e ire leyendo y viendo videos para ir aprendiendo, si puedes pasate por mi otra pregunta a ver si me puedes ayudar. Mil gracias.

Comment: @juanpinzon Juan, si notaste un -1 fue mio estoy en un mobile y por error di click, excelente respuesta, saludos!

Comment: @Elenasys no hay problema :), saludos!