# Botón funcional en Java

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing

Buenas necesito ayuda en java, estoy haciendo un menú gráfico en netbeans con la parte de hacer menús que ya tiene incorporada que es arrastrar las opciones y se hace el menú, al colocar un botón y darle doble click aparece el código del menú y para editarlo, necesito ayuda para hacer que ese boton realize por ejemplo una operación matemática de suma como se tendría que poner el código o que se abría que hacer, les agradecería muchísimo su ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
NetBeans tiene la opción de hacer los menús por objetos solo arrastrando las opciones y al darle doble click al botón sale el código del menú ya generado por el compilador, lo que quiero es que en ese botón en su código introducir una función por ejemplo una operación de suma o abrir un documento, que al pulsar el botón genere dicha operación.
Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
package empresa;

public class Menu extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public Menu() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(132, 132, 132)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(187, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(97, 97, 97)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(177, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
//AQUI VA LA ACCION A EJECUTAR EL BOTON
    }                                        


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Menu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Menu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Menu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Menu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }



        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Menu().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Listo agregue una imagen y una explicacion no se si me di a entender.

Comment: Ve lo que necesito hacer es un menu basado en una empresa, por ejemplo que una de las opciones me mande a un inventario, ese inventario estaria hecho en excel que me serviria para eso, pero lo que no se es la linea de codigo para que me ejecute dicho archivo. Ese seria un ejemplo de lo que tendria el menu basandose en la empresa.

Comment: si hablas de menus puedes utilizar JMenuBar, JMenu, JMenuItem

Comment: Creo que no me entiendes :(

Comment: mira para escuchar eventos con los botones o cualquier tipo de componente, lo primero que debe haces es implementar la interface `ActionListener` algo así: `public class Formulario extends JFrame implements ActionListener`, luego estas obligados a crear el método `actionPerformed`.

Comment: Agregue otra imagen que es donde se coloca el código de la acción a ejecutar el boton

Comment: por favor déjame ver el código de la clase `menu`

Comment: Te paso todo el codigo ese es el que crea por defecto netbeans lo dejo en la pregunta

Answer (score 2):

Hola al principio me confundí como gdaimon ya que comentabas no deseabas usar `JMenuBar` y `JMenu`, pongo un ejemplo para realizar una operación de suma.

Agrega dos `JTextField` para introducir los valores que deseas sumar y otro para agregar el resultado, entonces tendríamos:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        //AQUI VA LA ACCION A EJECUTAR EL BOTON
        double valor1, valor2, resultado;
        //obtienes los valores a sumar que están introducidos en los JTextField. 
        valor1 = Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());
        valor2 = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());
        //Realizas la suma.
        resultado = valor1 + valor2;
        //El resultado es agregado al JTextField destinado para mostrarlo.
        jTextFieldResultado.setText(String.valueOf(resultado));

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

mira lo que pasa es que el IDE te crea mucho código innecesario lo puedes implementar de la siguiente forma y es mas fácil de entender, creo que esto te servirá:

```
public class Prueba extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JButton boton1;

public Prueba() {
 setLayout(null);
 boton1=new JButton("Click");
 boton1.setBounds(300,250,100,30);
 add(boton1);
 boton1.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  if (e.getSource()==boton1) {
      System.out.println("Funciona...!");
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\\"Users\\Administrador\\Desktop\"\\File.xls");
        } catch (IOException error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
 }

public static void main(String[] ar) {
  Prueba prueba=new Prueba();
  prueba.setBounds(0,0,450,350);
  prueba.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Comment: Alli lo que se esta es creando el menu con el boton?

Comment: no entiendo tu pregunta..?

Comment: Osea con el codigo que me mandaste lo que se esta creando es el menu y en el menu el boton que hara una funcion luego ??

Comment: lo que te pase es una ventana que tiene un botón que envía un mensaje a la consola cuando lo presionas.

Comment: a esooo me referia si era eso, pero osea lo que yo quiero hacer es que el boton abra por ejemplo un documento externo en excel por ejemplo, que al pulsarlo lo ejecute, pero me gustaria hacerlo con las plantillas que ya trae netbeans porque pienso que seria mas facil y rapido.

Comment: aqui va la ruta de tu archivo `--> C:\\\"Users\\Administrador\\Desktop\"\\File.xls"`

Comment: esa ruta la puedo cambiar no? puedo ponerla en la carpeta donde esta todo el codigo por si necesito correrlo en otra pc, que librerias se usarian estas dos import java.awt.Dimension;   import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

Comment: claro que la puedes cambiar, la ruta la defines tu...

Comment: esta bien y las librerias que se usarian serian esas que te dije?